# Como hacer que tu apk funcione para apis menores y mayores que 23

Tags: android-studio, api

estoy intentando que mi apk funcione en apis mayores y menores que 23 pero no se como hacerlo. Estuve buscando y para hacer que funcione para mayores o menores que 23 se haría con la siguiente linea de código.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
                int permiso = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
                if (permiso == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    chamarTelefono();
                }
                else{
                    I3Aa19alexnp.this.requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},CODIGO_IDENTIFICADOR);
                }
```

En la parte del if especifico lo que hacer cuando la versión es mayor o igual que 23, y ahí podría poner también menor que 23; pero para poner las dos como tendría que hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas "apis menores y mayores que 23" lo validarias de esta forma

```
if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) && (Build.Build.VERSION_CODES.M > Build.VERSION_CODES.M)){

 ...
 ...

}
```

Donde `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` es la API 23

Comment: muchas gracias!!